# traversing huffman tree

Tags: java, tree, huffman-code

So I'm having a problem with traversing my huffmann tree and finding the code for the path to each char. Basically what i did is this: I used a FileReader to read the file, get each byte and then treat it as a char, then i placed it in a `char[]` array and used another `int[]` array to save the correspondent frequencies for each char. After that I created Tree objects by moving through the arrays and using the char and frequency. Each Tree i created i stored it into a `tree[]` array and then used that array to create a final huffman tree. Now i don't know how to move through the tree to find the path to the chars and create the path code. I've been coding for barely 5 months so I'm no expert, I know that for the path code, right is 0, left is 1 and i was planning on storing those values in another array but after reading through some of the earlier posts I figured it was a bad idea.
help please! my tree follows below.

```
private void crearArbol(){
  arbol = new Arbol[cantidadSimbolos];
  for(int i = 0; i < cantidadSimbolos; ++i){
     arbol[i] = new Arbol(charsDelArchivo[i], frecuenciaChars[i]);     
  }
  while(arbol.length > 1){
     Arbol [] provisional = new Arbol[arbol.length-1];
     for(int p = 2; p <arbol.length; ++p){
        provisional[p-1] = arbol[p];      
     }
     provisional[0] = new Arbol(arbol[0].getFrecuencia()+arbol[1].getFrecuencia());
     provisional[0].adoptarHijos(arbol[0], arbol[1]);
     this.arbol = provisional;
     ordenarVectores(0);
     System.gc();
  }
}
```

This one I wrote to create the huffman tree by moving through the arrays of each char and corresponding frequency... 
ps. our professor does not allow us to use java libraries such as ArrayList and such yet, no idea why, he likes to make stuff complicated.

Comment: Have you ever coded a binary tree? Implementing trees with arrays would not be a good idea. You should create the binary tree data structure by yourself. It's not difficult :)

Comment: umm well this would be my first binary tree ever haha i know the basic structure but i dont understand a few things... first, well what i did in that piece of code is create an array full of trees(which are actually leaves at the beginning) and then take the first two, create the new tree with those two as "sons" and then add that to the array... the problem is, i think by switching the arrays im actually killing the tree's sons... should i use a list instead of an array?